# How to prioritise Networkadapters in Windows

Tags: windows, redirect, networking, tcp, routes

I have a Windows 7 / 8.1 Laptop in a docking station connected via 2 networkadapters(LAN & WiFi) to 1 private network.

Now an application should connect to a Server inside this private network but first prio should have the LAN adapter. If the laptop gets removed from the docking station it should switch automaticaly to the WiFi adapter without losing connection or TCP packages.

I'm at the opinion that not the application layer is responsible for that. The switching and TCP packet resending should be managed by the OS.

However I don't know how to setup Windows for that, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your network adapters (Control Panel ->..) --> (then press alt for menu bar) --> [image: Connections]

In the following settings you can change the order / priority of the adapters:
[image: Settings]

I dont know if connection can changed without losing connection or TCP packages shortly, cause Windows normaly says: I have a connection - why i should also hold the second active ? 
Therefor you can look at the energyoptions of the pc for standbytime of the wifi-adapter and set it to highest performance, but i dont know if this will help properly.